# Insert the new globe by google maps on my own webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I need to put a 3d globe in my webpage and I've recently seen the new google maps' globe, and it's wonderful!

You can find it at:  https://www.google.com/maps/@24.0333789,-47.7758766,11512371m/data=!3m1!1e3

Now my question is:

Is there a way for put this globe on my webpage with the google maps javascript api (or with others google apis)?

( I don't need to link google maps's globe on something like an iframe, but I have to use it as a piece of my page and program it with javascript )

I know that I can do the same thing of the google's globe with cesiumjs, but I think that the google's one is better.

p.s. Sorry if my english is not very correct, this is not my native language, I do my best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have looked around for you, and it does not seem like google has an api for it, and they depricated the google earth api as well. this is sad to be honest, you can read more about it here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130910/google-earth-plugin-deprecated-which-alternatives

Comment: I hope in a future release. Thank you for your answer!